# svg transform moves image offscreen when going up

Tags: svg, snap.svg

**Objective:**
To move an svg image (elevator car) along a y-axis in the upwards or downwards position.

The image moves as I would like but the problem is that when it goes upwards, it disappears off the screen. I learned that altering the height of the viewBox:
`viewBox="0 0 900.7 701.9"` (701.9) in this instance would increase the box in where this svg would stay visible.

Although, it seems that this only lets me move it downwards more, not upwards.

I have a jsfiddle set up that gets right to the point. As much as I have read about the svg viewBox, I feel like I am not understanding something about it. Please take a look, thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/adamb7x/ungetpax/22/

Comment: You start the object at the top of the SVG canvas and when you move it up it's outside that area. If you started it lower you'd have room to move up.

Comment: @RobertLongson It sounds like I should have it set in the middle of the canvas to give it enough room to move up and down. Where can I change the position of the object in regards to the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going off the top of the SVG canvas. If you start lower you'll have more room to go up.

I've wrapped the drawing in an extra `<g>` tag that translates stuff down as Snap doesn't seem to have additive animation support.

```js
var rearCab = Snap('#RearCab');
  var rCab = rearCab.select('#RCab');

 
  document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click",function(){
  rCab.animate({
   transform: 't0,-350'
  }, 1000);
 })
  
document.getElementById("down").addEventListener("click",function(){
  rCab.animate({
   transform: 't0,350'
  }, 1000);
 })
```

```css
div.rearCab{
 top: 30%;
 left: 30%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
}

.st0 {
  clip-path: url(#SVGID_2_);
  fill: url(#SVGID_3_);
}

.st1 {
  fill: #1C1C1C;
}

.st2 {
  clip-path: url(#SVGID_5_);
  fill: url(#SVGID_6_);
}

.st3 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_7_);
}

.st4 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_8_);
}

.st5 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_9_);
}

.st6 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_10_);
}

.st7 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_11_);
}

.st8 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_12_);
}

.st9 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_13_);
}

.st10 {
  display: none;
}

.st11 {
  display: inline;
}

.st12 {
  clip-path: url(#SVGID_15_);
  fill: url(#SVGID_16_);
}

.st13 {
  display: inline;
  fill: #1C1C1C;
}

.st14 {
  clip-path: url(#SVGID_18_);
  fill: url(#SVGID_19_);
}

.st15 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_20_);
}

.st16 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_21_);
}

.st17 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_22_);
}

.st18 {
  fill: url(#SVGID_23_);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<div class="rearCab">
  <svg version="1.1" id="RearCab" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 900.7 901.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100.7 151.9;" xml:space="preserve">

    <g  transform="translate(0, 350)">
    <g id="RCab">
      <g id="RightDoorRear_1_">
        <g id="RightDoorRear">
          <g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <defs>
                          <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="50.1" y="25.6" width="28.4" height="116.5" />
                        </defs>
                        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;" />
                        </clipPath>

                        <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1799.5736" y1="-924.9411" x2="-1741.5736" y2="-924.9411" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 -1721.0736 1008.1411)">
                          <stop offset="2.688172e-02" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                          <stop offset="0.2742" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.439" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.5121" style="stop-color:#C1C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.5215" style="stop-color:#C0C1C3" />
                          <stop offset="0.6609" style="stop-color:#C2C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.7111" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.7204" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.7608" style="stop-color:#C1C2C4" />
                          <stop offset="0.8282" style="stop-color:#A7A9AB" />
                          <stop offset="0.9138" style="stop-color:#7E7F81" />
                          <stop offset="0.9785" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <polygon class="st0" points="20.5,24.3 78.5,24.3 78.5,142.1 20.5,142.1          " />
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <rect x="49.8" y="25.6" class="st1" width="0.3" height="116.5" />
      </g>
      <g id="LeftDoorRear">
        <g id="LeftDoor">
          <g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <defs>
                          <rect id="SVGID_4_" x="21.5" y="25.6" width="28.8" height="116.5" />
                        </defs>
                        <clipPath id="SVGID_5_">
                          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_4_" style="overflow:visible;" />
                        </clipPath>

                        <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="21.5" y1="106.7" x2="80.4" y2="106.7" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 191.2)">
                          <stop offset="2.688172e-02" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                          <stop offset="0.2742" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.439" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.5121" style="stop-color:#C1C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.5215" style="stop-color:#C0C1C3" />
                          <stop offset="0.6609" style="stop-color:#C2C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.7111" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.7204" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.7608" style="stop-color:#C1C2C4" />
                          <stop offset="0.8282" style="stop-color:#A7A9AB" />
                          <stop offset="0.9138" style="stop-color:#7E7F81" />
                          <stop offset="0.9785" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <rect x="21.5" y="25.6" class="st2" width="58.9" height="117.8" />
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <rect x="49.8" y="25.6" class="st1" width="0.3" height="116.5" />
      </g>
      <g id="CeilingandFloor">

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-5430.1064" y1="244.7255" x2="-5430.1064" y2="178.3705" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.8862 0 0 -1 -4729.9604 231.2)">
          <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#E5E2DF" />
          <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#D9D4D0" />
          <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#CCC6C1" />
          <stop offset="6.668396e-02" style="stop-color:#BDB8B4" />
          <stop offset="0.1461" style="stop-color:#A6A29F" />
          <stop offset="0.8764" style="stop-color:#A6A29F" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#D0D2D3" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#A6A8AB" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon class="st3" points="85.9,14.7 78.5,25.2 78.5,151.9 85.9,151.9  " />

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_8_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="18.15" y1="245.4305" x2="18.15" y2="178.7922" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 231.2)">
          <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#E5E2DF" />
          <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#D9D4D0" />
          <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#CCC6C1" />
          <stop offset="6.668396e-02" style="stop-color:#BDB8B4" />
          <stop offset="0.1461" style="stop-color:#A6A29F" />
          <stop offset="0.8764" style="stop-color:#A6A29F" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#D0D2D3" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#A6A8AB" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon class="st4" points="14.8,14.1 21.5,24.7 21.5,151.9 14.8,151.9  " />

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_9_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-4755.9702" y1="-2614.2454" x2="-4755.9702" y2="-2628.8735" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 -4705.5703 2768.1921)">
          <stop offset="0.2903" style="stop-color:#555658" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#231F20" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polyline class="st5" points="14.9,151.9 21.5,142.1 78.5,142.1 85.9,151.9 14.9,151.9  " />

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-4094.2314" y1="1633.9298" x2="-4094.2314" y2="1571.3958" gradientTransform="matrix(0 1 1 0 -1547.031 4095.8813)">
          <stop offset="0.1828" style="stop-color:#96999B" />
          <stop offset="0.5608" style="stop-color:#A1A3A6" />
          <stop offset="0.957" style="stop-color:#A6A8AB" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon class="st6" points="3.5,3.3 3.5,0 97.5,0 97.5,3.3  " />

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="50.4" y1="219.3384" x2="50.4" y2="213.8274" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 231.2)">
          <stop offset="0.457" style="stop-color:#48484A" />
          <stop offset="0.8495" style="stop-color:#898B8D" />
          <stop offset="0.9677" style="stop-color:#48484A" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon class="st7" points="21.5,25.6 14.9,19.9 14.9,14.2 85.9,14.2 85.9,19.3 78.5,25.6  " />

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_12_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="50.5" y1="232.7484" x2="50.5" y2="214.6539" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 231.2)">
          <stop offset="1.612903e-02" style="stop-color:#E6E7E8" />
          <stop offset="0.4194" style="stop-color:#B9BBBD" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4A4A4C" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon class="st8" points="3.5,3.3 14.9,14.7 86.1,14.7 97.5,3.4  " />
        <g>

          <image style="overflow:visible;opacity:0.75;enable-background:new    ;" width="42" height="35" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 29 3.9)">
          </image>
          <g>

            <linearGradient id="SVGID_13_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="44.0384" y1="210.2" x2="55.9487" y2="210.2" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 231.2)">
              <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#E5E2DF" />
              <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#D9D4D0" />
              <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#CCC6C1" />
              <stop offset="6.668396e-02" style="stop-color:#BDB8B4" />
              <stop offset="0.1461" style="stop-color:#A6A29F" />
              <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" />
              <stop offset="0.5796" style="stop-color:#F1F1F0" />
              <stop offset="0.7315" style="stop-color:#CDCBC9" />
              <stop offset="0.8764" style="stop-color:#A6A29F" />
              <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#D0D2D3" />
              <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#A6A8AB" />
            </linearGradient>
            <ellipse class="st9" cx="50" cy="21" rx="6" ry="2" />
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g id="LeftDoor_2_" class="st10">
        <g id="RightDoor_2_" class="st11">
          <g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <defs>
                          <rect id="SVGID_14_" x="14.8" y="14.7" width="35.5" height="137.2" />
                        </defs>
                        <clipPath id="SVGID_15_">
                          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_14_" style="overflow:visible;" />
                        </clipPath>

                        <linearGradient id="SVGID_16_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1020.2736" y1="-925.5911" x2="-947.7736" y2="-925.5911" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1035.0736 1008.1411)">
                          <stop offset="2.688172e-02" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                          <stop offset="0.2742" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.439" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.5121" style="stop-color:#C1C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.5215" style="stop-color:#C0C1C3" />
                          <stop offset="0.6609" style="stop-color:#C2C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.7111" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.7204" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.7608" style="stop-color:#C1C2C4" />
                          <stop offset="0.8282" style="stop-color:#A7A9AB" />
                          <stop offset="0.9138" style="stop-color:#7E7F81" />
                          <stop offset="0.9785" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <polygon class="st12" points="87.3,151.9 14.8,151.9 14.8,13.2 87.3,13.2          " />
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <rect x="50.2" y="14.7" class="st13" width="0.3" height="137.2" />
      </g>
      <g id="RightDoor" class="st10">
        <g id="RightDoor_1_" class="st11">
          <g>
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                  <g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <defs>
                          <rect id="SVGID_17_" x="50.3" y="14.7" width="35.6" height="137.2" />
                        </defs>
                        <clipPath id="SVGID_18_">
                          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_17_" style="overflow:visible;" />
                        </clipPath>

                        <linearGradient id="SVGID_19_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1806.9736" y1="-925.5911" x2="-1734.4736" y2="-925.5911" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 -1721.0736 1008.1411)">
                          <stop offset="2.688172e-02" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                          <stop offset="0.2742" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.439" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.5121" style="stop-color:#C1C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.5215" style="stop-color:#C0C1C3" />
                          <stop offset="0.6609" style="stop-color:#C2C3C5" />
                          <stop offset="0.7111" style="stop-color:#C8CACC" />
                          <stop offset="0.7204" style="stop-color:#CACCCE" />
                          <stop offset="0.7608" style="stop-color:#C1C2C4" />
                          <stop offset="0.8282" style="stop-color:#A7A9AB" />
                          <stop offset="0.9138" style="stop-color:#7E7F81" />
                          <stop offset="0.9785" style="stop-color:#5A5B5D" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <polygon class="st14" points="13.4,13.2 85.9,13.2 85.9,151.9 13.4,151.9          " />
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <rect x="50.2" y="14.7" class="st13" width="0.3" height="137.2" />
      </g>
      <g id="LeftBar">

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_20_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="9.2" y1="258.4245" x2="9.2" y2="186.5748" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 231.2)">
          <stop offset="0.7527" style="stop-color:#616264" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#898B8D" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon class="st15" points="3.5,3.3 14.9,14.7 14.9,151.9 3.5,151.9  " />

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_21_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1.9" y1="214.1236" x2="1.9" y2="112.9763" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 231.2)">
          <stop offset="0.1828" style="stop-color:#87898B" />
          <stop offset="0.5404" style="stop-color:#7D7F81" />
          <stop offset="0.957" style="stop-color:#797B7D" />
        </linearGradient>
        <rect x="0.2" class="st16" width="3.4" height="151.9" />
      </g>
      <g id="RightBar">

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_22_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-5440.8267" y1="258.4242" x2="-5440.8267" y2="186.5752" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.8862 0 0 -1 -4729.9604 231.2)">
          <stop offset="0.7527" style="stop-color:#616264" />
          <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#898B8D" />
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon class="st17" points="97.5,3.3 85.9,14.7 85.9,151.9 97.5,151.9  " />

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_23_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="99.2" y1="214.1236" x2="99.2" y2="112.9763" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 231.2)">
          <stop offset="0.2043" style="stop-color:#77787B" />
          <stop offset="0.5796" style="stop-color:#6B6C6F" />
          <stop offset="0.957" style="stop-color:#67686B" />
        </linearGradient>
        <rect x="97.5" class="st18" width="3.4" height="151.9" />
      </g>
    </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<button  id="up">Up</button>
<button  id="down">Down</button>

</button>
```

Comment: Looks like that works! It seems that by default, an SVG will be placed on top of the canvas. Expanding the height of the viewBox only increases it going down. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Well yes, (0,0) is the origin and that's the top left.